# Trigger an event after all of the animations from current function completed

Tags: jquery, animation, random, mouseenter, easing

I've been trying to get a function to trigger only after all of the element's `.animate()` functions have been completed including the delay and easing.

I've tried a few different methods with no luck, any ideas?

```
  $("#inner_work").on("mouseenter", ".activeBox", function(){
        var thisBox = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#inner_work [class^='workBox_']").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') != thisBox){
                $(this).stop().delay(randomEasing(200,800)).animate({
                    opacity:0
                }, randomEasing(200,700));
            } else {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    opacity:1
                }, 'fast');
            }
        }); 
  });
```

How do I trigger an event AFTER all the animation has been completed?

`randomEasing` is just this function to make it randomly staggered

```
function randomEasing(from,to)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use deferred objects and request a [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to register a callback which will be invoked only when all animations on every element within the collection have completed:

```
$("#inner_work [class^='workBox_']").promise().done(function() { 
     ...
});
```

This can be chained with your existing code:

```
$("#inner_work [class^='workBox_']").each(function() {
    // your existing animation code
}).promise().done(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: p.s. use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: I have used `promise` and `done`,  if I have for example 10 elements within a jQuery collection, it takes 10 * duration and then callback is executed, is there any other way?

Comment: @undefined it shouldn't do that.  Have you got a jsfiddle to demonstrate that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, actually I had a project with many animations, this doesn't happen always. never mind, thanks.

Comment: @undefined see the caveat in the docs for `.promise()` that talk about what happens if you use it on an element that is subsequently removed before the promise is resolved.